# how to make image appear when check box is checked and disappear when unchecked(html)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

When a person clicks on a check box, I want a certain image to appear.
Im not sure if I use jquery, Ajax or not.
What DO I use?

I would appreciate if someone help. I have created the check box already but how do i link it
to a image to show and not to show when checked?

Comment: added a basic answer using jQuery, have a look on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you simply want to show the image, or have a toggle effect? Here is how to just show a hidden image.

CSS:

```
#your_img {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="show_image">Show Image</input>
<div id="your_img">
<img src="a.jpg" alt="A image" style="height: 200px;width:200px">
</div>
```

Javascript:

Script to show image once. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/826cV/1/

```
$('#show_image').one("click", function(){
    $('#your_img').show();
});
```

Script to toggle image. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/826cV/

```
$('#show_image').on("click", function(){
    if( $('#your_img').is(':hidden')) {
    $('#your_img').show();
    }else{
    $('#your_img').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="show_img()" id="check" value="whatever" name="whatever">whatever</input>
<div id="img"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function show_img(){
 if (document.getElementById("check").checked){
 document.getElementById("img").innerHTML="<img src='path to your image'>";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a very simple example for you

```
<input type="checkbox">Show Image</input>
<img src="a.jpg" alt="A image" style="height: 200px;width:200px">


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').hide();
  $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    this.checked?$('img').show():$('img').hide();
  })
});
```